# Timeline animation and AS3 Tween Class

Tags: actionscript-3, timeline, tween

Is there a way (using the AS 3 Tween Class, NOT TweenMax) to speed up a timeline animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tween = new Tween(this, 'frame', None.easeIn, 148, 172, .5, true)

private var _frame:int;

public function set frame(value:Number):void {
        _frame = int(value);
        myMovieClip.gotoAndStop(_frame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with timer, set interval lower than second(1000ms)/fps, and use nextFrame()

Comment: Okay, I just tried this, but setInterval appears to be making my .swf crash?

Comment: Try Timer class, setInterval is from as2 http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html