# as3 dynamic Tween duration

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

I have an object in a Movieclip that I currently have a tween set up for. I set it up on the stage, not with actionscript.

I need to dynamically change the duration of this tween. I have not found reference to a way to do this.

I don't mind dynamically creating the tween if I need to, setting the initial duration in code, but I still have not found any reference to changing the duration dynamically.

Is this possible?

I'm just learning as3, so sorry if this is something that should be obvious.

Comment: [Here's the doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#duration) that shows you how.

Comment: you can do it manually by either using a timer or an ENTER_FRAME event to update an int which will represent the current frame in your movie clip, or as the answers bellow suggest, use a tweening library that can tween movie clip frames (like eaze or tweenLite with the FramePlugin activated)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'd do it by programming the tween, there are many libraries out there that make it quite easy.

One of the ones I use frequently is [eaze-tween](http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/), it has a timeline tween function, though I haven't used it, it is worth a try. `eaze(target).to(duration, { frame:"label" });`

Grant Skinner's [gtween](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/) library also seems to be able to that using the GTweenTimeline Class.

The other thing you can do is modify the frame the animation is at at a varied rate, so to speed it up you'd go through it two frames at a time, so twice as fast. This way makes it limited to multiples of speed.

If you want to have more control there you'd need to have a longer tween, otherwise you might notice movement that is not very smooth. The way to do that would be to have a transition of a 100 frames, and use a tweening library, where the on update makes the value of the tween(which is a number between 0 and 1) and multiply it by the number of frames(100) and update the frame `mc.gotoAndStop(int(val*100);`. You can then assign various tweening functions and durations.

hope it helps

Comment: there was a similar question asked that shows the later salotion code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296929/timeline-animation-and-as3-tween-class

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to switch to TweenLite/TweenMax library, it's awesome, free, super-easy to use and it will change the way you work!
Have a look [here](http://www.greensock.com/), and [here on the forum](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/4597-changing-duration-on-the-fly-tweenlite/) there's an explanation on how to change duration dynamically

Comment: 100% agree. and for OP to tween something programatically with TweenLite/Max its as simple as `TweenLite.to(yourDisplayObject,yourDuration,{yourProperties});` so that would be like: `TweenLite.to(myMovieClip,0.5,{alpha:0,ease:Expo.easeOut});` That will tween myMovieClip's opacity to 0 in the span of a half second

Comment: there are many tweening libraries or engines but they don't really address the OP's question.

Comment: @Daniel the link I provide address it

Comment: @Daniel I reckon you will find that not only does TweenLite/Max address the OP's question it pretty much saves the universe

Comment: 'tis true, tweenMax and tweenLite have been known to remove calcium deposits in my shower.